# Referencing docker base images in a stable way (without digest)

Tags: docker, gcc

I am currently building a docker image on top of `gcc:11`. All the (newer) tags are pushed to (relatively) frequently which becomes annoying when my image build suddenly starts from base. Some docker registries offer dated tags (like `foo:3.0.1-20220714` for stability, which are never pushed to again. Gcc does not. Is there any other way to reference a tag in a stable way (like a git commit)? Or are tags just overwritten in the repository and that is why it is physically impossible?

EDIT: I forgot to mention this build is multi-platform, so I cannot reference by digest.

Comment: Also posted on https://forums.docker.com/t/referencing-images-in-a-stable-way/126712

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/ :

> Pull an image by digest (immutable identifier)
>
> So far, you’ve pulled images by their name (and “tag”). Using names
> and tags is a convenient way to work with images. When using tags, you
> can docker pull an image again to make sure you have the most
> up-to-date version of that image. For example, docker pull
> ubuntu:20.04 pulls the latest version of the Ubuntu 20.04 image.
>
> In some cases you don’t want images to be updated to newer versions,
> but prefer to use a fixed version of an image. Docker enables you to
> pull an image by its digest. When pulling an image by digest, you
> specify exactly which version of an image to pull. Doing so, allows
> you to “pin” an image to that version, and guarantee that the image
> you’re using is always the same.
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> docker pull ubuntu@sha256:82becede498899ec668628e7cb0ad87b6e1c371cb8a1e597d83a47fac21d6af3
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> FROM ubuntu@sha256:82becede498899ec668628e7cb0ad87b6e1c371cb8a1e597d83a47fac21d6af3
> ```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include that digest's are not an option due to the multi-platform use of this Dockerfile. Otherwise it would have been a pretty dumb question TBH.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question: This is now solved thanks to [@yosifkit](https://github.com/yosifkit) on Github: use the [docker manifest tool](https://github.com/estesp/manifest-tool). Here is the [original answer](https://github.com/docker-library/gcc/issues/85).

It can extract a digest which is not platform specific.